# Python. Как составить карту/схему/дерево вызова функций в классе?

Tags: python

Есть ли сторонняя разработка для составления "документа/дерева" очередности вызова функций в классе? Что-то наподобие :

```
my_def_1
  my_def_1_1, my_def_1_2, my_def_3_2
  my_def_2
  my_def_3_1, my_def_3_2, my_def_3_4, my_def_3_3
              my_def_4_1, my_def_4_2, my_def_3_2, my_def_3_1
```

Хочу прикрутить PyTest к готовой программе, но нужно определиться с чего начать проще, какие функции "узловые" (например my_def_3_2) - чтобы не упустить варианты их использования. Функций много, классов тоже. Вдруг есть решение для анализа класса подобного рода? Ну или куда копать ?

Comment: Может быть что-нибудь такое? https://pycallgraph.readthedocs.io/en/master/ Это если нужна именно визуализация, если текст - то подойдет дамп какого-нибудь профайлера

Comment: Используйте [pytest-cov](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-cov/) и поднимайте покрытие к 100%. Это полезнее чем исследовать деревья вызовов и смотреть как ваш анализ разваливается после рефакторинга.

Comment: Спасибо за советы, в ближайшее время попробую обязательно !